# Alerting user that datePicker set to today

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to stop the user from setting a notification for a date or time that is current ie. the time this post is created. Need advice on the code to make a UIAlert that when the button is pressed to create the alarm, they are told it is not possible. For example, do I use an if statement that says if button is pressed and time is minimum date, it is not possible else create the alarm? This will be my first app. and I just need to fiddle these bugs for tomorrow. The following code is used to schedule the alarm, would I use an if statement somewhere in there:

```
- (IBAction)scheduleAlarm:(id)sender {

    [self.eventText resignFirstResponder];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    //Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    //Unable to set notification for same day
    [datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];

    //Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components: (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components: (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *datePicker = [self.datePicker date];

    // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = datePicker;
    localNotification.alertBody = self.eventText.text;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
    localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    eventText.text = nil;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following after the datePicker line:

```
NSDate *datePicker = [self.datePicker date];
NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];
if ([dateNow compare:datePicker] == NSOrderedAscending) {

 // show alert and return

}
```

Comment: For some reason that didn't seem to work, it clears the field; but doesn't show the alert. And if I set the time after the minimum it then pops up.

Comment: Got this error jamihash: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDatePicker timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b833f20'